# Is it possible to add a delay to a dotnet watch command?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-watch

I am using dotnet watch command to get automatic reloading for my application and it works quite fine. The problem I encountered is that if I do run some other tool that does something similar there is some locking of resources that happens and one of the processes fails.

My example is that I run live unit testing in Rider.

What I thought might be an easy fix is to add some delay to dotnet watch, so that live testing has some seconds heads up to run before dotnet watch will do a rebuild.

I did not find though any possibility for that unfortunately. Is it possible to achieve with some clever trick?